# Глобальный класс

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Мне необходимо при запуске инициализировать класс:

`TestClass *class = [[TestClass alloc] init];`

и потом использовать `class` из любой точки программы, что бы все переменные в `class` сохранялись до завершения программы.

Я так понимаю надо создать `Constant.h`, прописать там глобальную переменную `class`, при запуске инициализировать `class` и импортировать `Constant.h` где мне надо.

Но вопрос в том как мне создать такую глобальную переменную? Не совсем в этом разбираюсь.

Comment: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko благодарю!